# python compute closeness of strings

Tags: python, string-comparison

I want to compare string representations of 3 or 4 digit integers. I want to group them to pairs of 'closeness'. That is, `pc_dud[3]` should pair with `dud[0]`.

```
dud = ['3433', '3467', '3551', '345', '345', '3613'] 
pc_dud = ['3401', '3402', '3430', '0342', '3584']
```

Does anyone know of a good tool out there to do this (I was thinking myself maybe something like jellyfish)? Another solution of course would be to use the arithmetical difference as an indicator for 'closeness'. Any thoughts?

Comment: [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module.

Comment: the difference would be easier, since they're just numbers anyways. if they were alphanumeric strings, then you'd do the equivalent levenshtein distance.

Comment: It depends on how exactly you want to minimize the differences, like if it is OK to sacrifice a pair so that all the others are much closer... If not, I'd sort the lists and zip both.

Comment: The lists are not of equal length, though.

Comment: Alternatively you might want to minimize the average differences, the maximum difference, ... Many ways of doing it, depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I misscounted! But my main point stands, you might want to minimize lots of things.

Comment: I doesn't have to be exact. Just a rough match.

Comment: Jejeje, I have absolutely no idea what you might mean by "rough match" ;)

Comment: True...It means that it is not a big drama if there are pairs that don't have a high matching score. Even a few wrong matches don't matter much.

Comment: Convert to integers and take the distance `abs(d1-d2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [difflib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module:

Example:

```
>>> import difflib
>>> dud = ['3433', '3467', '3551', '345', '345', '3613'] 
>>> pc_dud = ['3401', '3402', '3430', '0342', '3584']
>>> difflib.get_close_matches(dud[0], pc_dud)
['3430']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for arithmetical closeness, then pc_dud[3] will not match with dud[0].

If you want to only keep unique pairs use this:

```
dud_ = dud[:]
pc_dud_ = pc_dud[:]

while dud_:
    d1, d2 = min(itertools.product(dud, pc_dud), key=lambda d1,d2: abs(int(d1) - int(d2)))
    dud_.remove(d1)
    pc_dud_.remove(d2)
    print d1, d2
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach you may take is to compute the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between each integer string in dud compared to each integer string in pc_dud. This algorithm will yield you the edit distance between each sequence of numbers. The edit distance number indicates the minimum number of steps it would take to transform a given sequence to another sequence. It considers insertion, deletion, and substitution.

You will need a data structure to store the edit distance results relative to the sequence it was compared too. You can then investigate which edit distance is the smallest then group them as a pair.

Here is a visual example of what two sequences of numbers from your arrays would look like when compared with levenshtein. I used this tool to produce the screenshot. http://www.let.rug.nl/kleiweg/lev/

http://imgur.com/OTJia7W

The number in the bottom right corner is the minimum edit distance.

Comment: Actually, I didn't originally catch the emphasis on arithmetical difference. This may not be the best solution but could be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the Levenshtein Distance route as recommended by Paul, take a look at Apache's [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/)
- I believe lucene's FuzzyQuery is based on this.